# Access VBA SQL String Syntax eror

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to delete all multiple records in ARPs and I can#t figure out why this doesn't work. I get an Error 3075 when I run this in ACCESS saying:

> "Syntax Error in Date in Query 'ARPs.ARPNR  = 'CLU7BG' AND
>   ARPs.Änderungsdatum < #29.07.2016 12:21:42'"

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim allMult As DAO.Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT ARPs.ARPNR, ARPs.Änderungsdatum FROM ARPs WHERE ARPs.BTNR IN (SELECT BTNR FROM ARPs GROUP BY BTNR HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);"

Set allMult = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

With allMult

    'Check that the Recordset isn't empty
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then

        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst

        'Loop until we reach the end of the Recordset
        While (Not allMult.EOF)

            'Delete all except the newest multiple records
            strSQL = "DELETE * FROM ARPs WHERE ARPs.ARPNR  = '" & allMult.Fields("ARPNR") & "' AND ARPs.Änderungsdatum < #" & allMult.Fields("Änderungsdatum") & "# ;"

            CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

            .MoveNext
        Wend

    End If

    'close the Recordset
    .Close
End With

'release memory
Set allMult = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your allMult.Fields("Änderungsdatum") is a Date then you can use QueryDef to allow you to pass parameters.  In this case you don't need to worry about formatting.

```
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
  "DELETE FROM ARPs WHERE ARPNR = prm0 AND Änderungsdatum < prm1")
  .Parameters("prm0") = allMult.Fields("ARPNR") 
  .Parameters("prm1") = allMult.Fields("Änderungsdatum")
  .Execute
  .Close
End With
```

Using parameter queries is a good habit to get into.  Including strings in a SQL string for execution is generally bad practice.  Google SQL Injection to find out why.

Answer (score 2):

You need a properly formatted string expression for the date value:

```
strSQL = "DELETE * FROM ARPs WHERE ARPs.ARPNR = '" & allMult.Fields("ARPNR") & "' AND ARPs.Änderungsdatum < #" & Format(allMult.Fields("Änderungsdatum").Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# ;"
```

Comment: Don't forget the time (if required): `Format(allMult.Fields("Änderungsdatum").Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh:nn:ss")`

Comment: It works! Thanks! I thought it would be fine, because both of the dates are in the same format due to being from the same table originally.

Comment: Have in mind, that a date value is numeric and carries no format. The format applied in tables, queries, and forms is for display only.